# JavaME - Executing NetBeans application in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, java-me

I want to run my J2ME Application in Eclipse. Its made in Netbeans IDE but want to run in Eclipse. For that I installed J2ME plug-ins but I want emulator to run the application. Please send some link for installing emulator so I can run it in Eclipse as well.

Comment: Check this other question: run j2me app on android? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134366/run-j2me-app-on-android

Comment: @TelmoPimentelMota...Thanks...I want to run J2ME app in eclipse..for that I need an emulator.

Comment: @TelmoPimentelMota, she is not asking for J2ME to Android Conversion, please read the question properly.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding the question properly.

Comment: @TelmoPimentelMota...Its ok..Don't be sorry..at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import eclipse project into Netbeans as Netbeans has that utility, but for importing Netbeans project into Eclipse there is no default utility. You can try following steps,

- Create New Java ME Project in Eclipse
- Copy+Paste your src and res files from NetBeans to Eclipse
- Set the default Midlet execution property in to `Àpplication Descriptor` file.

Comment: @Lucifer...Hi..Thanks a lot...It works fine..and I have another query..Project I have paste from netbeans to Eclipse. But now error in json parsing code. Can you help me for that?

Comment: Actually I added json.jar file so its fine but now my error is....                                                        Uncaught exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/me/JSONObject
 - parsing.Parsing$1.run(), bci=88                                                                                                                                                                                                       Have you any solution for this?

Comment: i havent worked with json, but still i require the code, and it would be nice if you post a new question instead discuss here.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3592252/996493) might helpful for you.